# Looping through letters not working

Tags: php, string, for-loop

I have a function, that loops over excel columns. It was working yesterday, but now I am having issues. My function is returning `false` according to my `var_dump()` It isn't even entering the for loop (I have echoed out "here" within that loop and nothing was echoed). Why isn't it working?

`$max_col` does return the correct maximum column

```
function get_col(PHPExcel $excel, $search, $row = 5, $col = "A"){
    $max_col = (string)$excel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn(); // returns BH
    for($i = (string)$col; $i <= $max_col; $i++){
        $val    = trim($excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell("{$i}{$row}")->getValue());
        $search = preg_quote($search);
        if(preg_match("/$search/isU", $val)){
            return "$i";
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here is how I am calling the function:

```
$col = get_col($excel, $sku, 5, "Q");
var_dump($col);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `<=` comparison for strings will cause you problems because it's an alphabetic comparison, and alphabetically "C" > "BH"
Adjust the initial value of $max_col to be one column beyond the max you want to check, and then use a `!==` comparison

```
function get_col(PHPExcel $excel, $search, $row = 5, $col = "A"){
    $max_col = $excel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn(); // returns BH
    $max_col++;
    for($i = $col; $i !== $max_col; $i++){
        $val    = trim($excel->getActiveSheet()->getCell("{$i}{$row}")->getValue());
        $search = preg_quote($search);
        if(preg_match("/$search/isU", $val)){
            return "$i";
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```